# Attribute Error Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I 'm not sure why I am getting an attribute error in the following code when I try to access the instance's attribute score:

```
class EllipseMaker(Widget):
    score = 10


class Modules(GridLayout):
    moduleone = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        print self.moduleone.score
```

In my .kv doc:

```
<Modules>:
    cols:1
    moduleone: ellipseone
    EllipseMaker:
        id: ellipseone
        size: (root.width/4,root.height/4)
        pos: self.parent.center

<EllipseMaker>:
   canvas:
       Ellipse:
           pos:self.pos
           size:self.size
```

The error I am getting is "AttributeError: 'EllipseMaker' object has no attribute 'score'"

Comment: Try with `self.score = 10`

Comment: works fine on my side.

Comment: it still gives me the same error

Comment: @Jamie: Post some working code that we can test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had another .kv file in which EllipseMaker was already defined, so the program kept referencing that EllipseMaker class instead.